# Is there a standard static function wrapper type template?

Tags: c++, c++14

I am looking for a standard C++14 type template that statically (at compile time) embeds a function reference as a template argument and implements `operator()` as a forwarding call to the referenced function.

I know that `std::function` exists, but it stores a function pointer as a data member. I want the function reference to be embedded in the type signature so that the wrapper type is *empty* and *default-constructible*.

I have a working implementation (with example use case):

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// Implementation:

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct fn_t {
    template <Ret (Func)(Args...)>
    struct fn_ref {
        Ret operator () (Args &&...args) const {
            return Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };
};

// Example use case:

template <typename T>
using unique_c_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, fn_t<void, void *>::fn_ref<std::free>>;

int main() {
    // { char *, void (*)(void *) } (16 bytes)
    std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(&std::free)> ptr1(::strdup("Hello"), &std::free);

    // { char *, fn_t<void, void *>::fn_ref<std::free> } (8 bytes)
    unique_c_ptr<char[]> ptr2(::strdup("Hello"));

    std::cout << sizeof ptr1 << '\n'       // 16
              << sizeof ptr2 << std::endl; // 8
    return 0;
}
```

`ptr1` and `ptr2` work alike, but `ptr2` is half the size because it doesn't need to store a pointer to `std::free`.

My question: Is there a standard-library way of doing this, such that I need not define `fn_t` and `fn_ref`?

Comment: A function is a type.

Comment: @JoelCornett: A function is not a type. If you try to provide `std::free` as a type argument, the compiler emits an error: "type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list" ("note: expected a type, got 'free'"). A function *has* a type, but a function *is* not a type. And the type of a function is not unique to that function. `decltype(std::free)` is `void (void *) throw ()`, and this type has no `operator ()`.

Comment: haha whoops that was a 'type-o' on my part. I meant the inverse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `std::integral_constant` which does the job:

```
 using CFree = std::integral_constant<void (*)(void*), std::free>;
```

As it may convert to its value, you may use same syntax to call `operator()`.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1f62efa22831990)

Comment: :) clever, but I still think that writing a custom functor is more expressive.

Comment: Also, `integral_constant` has its own `operator()`, which means that this doesn't work on functions with no parameters.

Comment: Cunning! I was not familiar with `std::integral_constant<…>::operator value_type`. @T.C. has a good point about the `operator()` that will preclude this trick from working for nullary functions, but I think almost every time I've wanted to embed a function reference in a type signature, the function has taken at least one argument, so I'll accept this answer. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, this is far enough from the intended use case of `integral_constant` that I doubt that the committee would hesitate before breaking it if required for some other feature.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, no.

But one might argue that it's more succinct (and might even require fewer keystrokes) to simply create a trivial functor type to invoke the function you want.

My feeling is that this is easier to reason about:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// Implementation:

struct invoke_free
{
  void operator()(void*p) const noexcept {
    std::free(p);
  }
};

template <typename T>
using unique_c_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, invoke_free>;

// Example use case:


int main() {

    // { char *, fn_t<void, void *>::fn_ref<std::free> } (8 bytes)
    unique_c_ptr<char[]> ptr2(::strdup("Hello"));

    std::cout << sizeof ptr2 << std::endl; // 8
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"The short answer is, no"* See my answer.